# Derived methods in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa

`Spring Data JPA` documentation tells us that we can have derived methods for `delete` functionality. Then the documentation gives example as:

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

   long deleteByLastname(String lastname);

   List<User> removeByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

What I found confusing was `removeByLastname`. The `CrudRepository` has `delete` methods which start by `delete` word and there is no method which starts with `remove`. Do we have methods starting with `remove`? If yes, when and how to use them.

Link for the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both can be used the same way. You can either name your method to start with `remove` or `delete`. See [PartTree](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java) class for DELETE patterns:

`private static final String DELETE_PATTERN = "delete|remove";`

Comment: Satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

When generating the repository implementation, Spring Data examines any methods
in the repository interface, parses the method name, and attempts to understand the
method’s purpose in the context of the persisted object. In
essence, Spring Data defines a sort of miniature domain-specific language (DSL)
where persistence details are expressed in repository method signatures.
There is no difference between `remove` and `delete`. You can use any of them. Same
with `find` `get` `read`

Answer (score -1):

I believe they are using `List<User> removeByLastname(String lastname);` because there is already `long deleteByLastname(String lastname);` and you can't have a function with the same name and arguments

In modern versions of Spring Data JPA (>=1.7.x) query derivation for delete and remove operations are accessible

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/jpa-derived-delete-queries.html

Comment: But then how is the implementation provided for these two different naming conventions? Is `remove` a valid naming convention in `Spring Data JPA`?

Comment: yes, remove and delete both work in JPA 1.7 and later